# Multiple projects in a solution with just one Config file by environment

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, web-config, projects-and-solutions

I have several projects in a .NET Solution, and I want to decentralize all the configuration for all the different environments of the app to a "Web.Environment.Config" (Web.Dev.Config, Web.Pre.Config, etc...)

The problem is that one of the projects, a Class Library called Services, is the responsible of database and WS connections, and seems that the config could not be decentralized (or I do not know how to).

This is the "config tree" of the Solution:

```
- Solution
|-- Services (Class Library)
   |-- app.config
|-- WebService (WebServices project to expose some services)
   |-- Web.Debug.config
   |-- Web.Dev.config
   |-- Web.Pre.config
|-- Web (Web Application)
   |-- Web.Debug.config
   |-- Web.Dev.config
   |-- Web.Pre.config
```

As all the database connections is realized inside the Services project, I can not decentralize the config.

**My objective is to have all the configuration in just one config file by environment (in all the Solution). Is it possible?**